# Calling Sub Channel Entries

Tags: entries-field, channels

How would you go about pulling a selected entry from one channel into another entry using Craft variables?

For example, I have a page with an author channel field that allows a user to select the author from entries in an author channel. Once selected, I am wanting the page to display the author content from the selected Author entry.

I have tried using the following but have gotten no output.

```
{% if entry.authorTeamMember|length %} 
    {% set myEntry = entry.authorTeamMember.first() %}

    {{entry.authorName}}
    {{entry.authorDescription}}
{% else %}
    <p>No Author</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to adjust Brads code slightly and tweak it to get what I wanted.

Issue: I was getting some entrys but not all the entrys I wanted when I was pulling a list as one of my entryfields for my page was a channel.

When I was pulling the information for my authorName from myEntry, myEntry was assigned to the channel field and would only pick up and register the first author entry i created. I had to change `{{ myEntry.AuthorName }}` to `{{ myEntry.Title }}` as the channel entry for each author had a title field.

```
{% if entry.authorTeamMember|length %} 
    {% set myEntry = entry.authorTeamMember.first() %}

    {{ myEntry.Title }}
    {{ myEntry.authorDescription }}
{% else %}
    <p>No Author</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close!

You select the author correctly with and assign it to the `myEntry` variable:

```
{% set myEntry = entry.authorTeamMember.first() %}
```

Now you just need to output the data from `myEntry` instead of `entry`.  i.e.

```
{% if entry.authorTeamMember|length %} 
    {% set myEntry = entry.authorTeamMember.first() %}

    {{ myEntry.authorName }}
    {{ myEntry.authorDescription }}
{% else %}
    <p>No Author</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was overlooking something simple somewhere!

Comment: So working with it, it will pull the first entry in the authorTeamMember channel perfectly but wont recognize other authors if the code is in a loop pulling other entries for other authors. I am thinking it has to do with the .first() tag when I am setting  the variable myEntry.  Is there a way in the set tag to set entry.authorTeamMember to whatever option a is selected per article?